# Remove everything except email addresses from text using REGEX only

Tags: regex

**EDIT:** I have no access to "replace" function, to any code, or to the REGEX matches. All I can do is provide a regex string to the API, and it strips out whatever was matched (not part of an email), and leaves the rest (leaving behind only emails).

---

I am working with an API that reads data from an OCR document. I have no control over the API, however I have access to a function in the API which can **strip out whatever is matched by a provided REGEX**. I am trying to strip out whatever is NOT an email address, leaving only the email addresses behind, *separated by spaces if there is more than one email*. I know REGEX isn't the best for matching emails, but I have no other choice here.

Thanks to the OCR document, there are often characters that should not be present in an email e.g the text could be (simple example) `User Email:user@example.com*required field` and I would like to end up with just `user@example.com` by stripping out the rest.

1. I can't define or use regex replace or any other functions. All I can do is *define a regex for what to strip off* (basically I need to *invert* an email match).
2. I certainly don't expect this to work for all RFC-compliant email addresses, just reasonably most use-cases.
3. In case it matters, I happen to know the architecture of the API is in C#

Here is what I tried (non-working) to use to invert the email match, but it doesn't match anything.

```
^(?![A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}(?!.)
```

I also searched SO and [found this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410519/regular-expression-that-matches-everything-except-email-addresses) but it was inconclusive.

Comment: The problem is that either you will get concatenated (glued to one another) email addresses, or if you use some separator, a lot of these separators. It is done with either `([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})|.` => `$1` (or `\1`), or `$1\n` (`\1\n`).

Comment: Yes, email addresses separated by spaces are totally fine for this purpose, if there is more than one email address. The REGEX I posted just doesn't seem to match anything though. What do you think is wrong with it, please?

Comment: The main thing is that regex is invalid. And you wanted to use a non-consuming pattern to replace text - it is nonsense. To replace text, we MUST consume it. Lookarounds are used to check for presence or absence without actually putting the matched text into match value.

Comment: So, is replacing `([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})|.` with `$1<space>` works for you?

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew not sure I understand you. I have no access to "replace" or to the matches. All I can do is provide a regex string to the API, and it strips out whatever was matched, and leaves the rest (leaving behind only emails). is my question clearer?

Comment: Then you are stuck if you do not have a PCRE regex engine. Try `([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})\s?(*SKIP)(*F)|(?s).`.

Comment: In your case, it's not good enough that you can see an email address since you can't match it and therefore can't move the search position past it. There is however a self contained engine construct in the PCRE-like engines where the engine can do this maneuver without returning. There are other ways like matching the email, then ignoring it in a callback, but that is out of your control in this case.

Comment: Have a look at a [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69829851/3832970) I have just given, the first one is basically the same as I suggest here.

Comment: @wiktor The API returned "failed to execute REGEX function" so I am guessing the *SKIP instruction was not compatible.
sln: Please do you have an example of the self contained engine construct I can try? It is C# so it has only partial PCRE compliance.

Comment: Not really a C# equivalent of SKIP/FAIL that I know of. However if you had access to a callback you could match the email and create a list, effectively removing all except those. Unfortunately it doesn't appear yo can do that.

Comment: Since C# has variable width look behinds, you might try this though `(?:(?<=[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})|^)(?:(?![A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})[\S\s])+` Probably very slow. Note that you should replace with a space for separation.

Comment: @sln Thanks for your help, but sadly this stripped out all the data and I just ended up with an empty string. May need to contact the company behind the API.

Comment: Oh, wait you may have to set the case insensitive. I'm testing another regex.

Comment: I think I have found a way if it is .NET, but the pattern will look rather monstrous and not readable/maintainable.

Comment: Ok, I tested this on regexstorm `(?i)(?:(?<=([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.(?:[A-Z]{2,3}(?![A-Z])|[A-Z]{4})))|^)((?:(?![A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})[\S\s])+)` works. This was input `wklwLLO@REDE.com ujh  kjwklwLLO@REDE.comsrgfn`

Comment: I had to do some magic tweek in the lookbehind `(?:[A-Z]{2,3}(?![A-Z])|[A-Z]{4})` simulates `[A-Z]{2,4}` since in lookbehinds, ranges are treated non-greedy bias. FWIW I would try to replace with a space or newline to get some separation for viewing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in C#, uses variable look behind.

```
(?i)(?:(?<=([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.(?:[A-Z]{2,3}(?![A-Z])|[A-Z]{4})(?!\.[A-Z]{2})))|^)((?:(?![A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})[\S\s])+)
```

[RegexStormSample](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fi%29%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3c%3d%28%5bA-Z0-9._%25%2b-%5d%2b%40%5bA-Z0-9.-%5d%2b%5c.%28%3f%3a%5bA-Z%5d%7b2%2c3%7d%28%3f!%5bA-Z%5d%29%7c%5bA-Z%5d%7b4%7d%29%28%3f!%5c.%5bA-Z%5d%7b2%7d%29%29%29%7c%5e%29%28%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%5bA-Z0-9._%25%2b-%5d%2b%40%5bA-Z0-9.-%5d%2b%5c.%5bA-Z%5d%7b2%2c4%7d%29%5b%5cS%5cs%5d%29%2b%29&i=alk+JKJ%40yhahR.nhtf.com+dasfb&r=+)

Left a couple captures to fully view the parts.
Did a few tweaks in the lookbehind because it looks like in C#, lookbehind ranges are treated with non-greedy bias.
And they have to be controled with extra sub assertions to make it grab all the sub domain.

```
 (?i)
 (?:
    (?<=
       (                             # (1 start)
          [A-Z0-9._%+-]+ @ [A-Z0-9.-]+ \.
          (?:
             [A-Z]{2,3} 
             (?! [A-Z] )
           | [A-Z]{4} 
          )
          (?! \. [A-Z]{2} )
       )                             # (1 end)
    )
  | ^
 )
 (                             # (2 start)
    (?:
       (?! [A-Z0-9._%+-]+ @ [A-Z0-9.-]+ \. [A-Z]{2,4} )
       [\S\s]
    )+
 )                             # (2 end)
```

Comment: That regex fails validation when not used in a C# context.

Comment: @AndyUK It was specifically written to target C#

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a negative lookbehind pattern like

```cs
(?s)(?<![\w.%+-]+@[\w.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{0,3}(?=[A-Za-z])|[\w.%+-]+@[\w.-]*(?=[\w.-]*\.[A-Za-z]{2,3})|(?=[\w.%+-]*@[\w.-]*\.[A-Za-z]{2,3})).
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%0d%0a++%5b%5cw.%25%2b-%5d%2b%40%5b%5cw.-%5d%2b%5c.%5bA-Za-z%5d%7b0%2c3%7d%28%3f%3d%5bA-Za-z%5d%29%7c%0d%0a++%5b%5cw.%25%2b-%5d%2b%40%5b%5cw.-%5d*%28%3f%3d%5b%5cw.-%5d*%5c.%5bA-Za-z%5d%7b2%2c3%7d%29%7c%0d%0a++%28%3f%3d%5b%5cw.%25%2b-%5d*%40%5b%5cw.-%5d*%5c.%5bA-Za-z%5d%7b2%2c3%7d%29%0d%0a%29.&i=User+Email%3auser%40example.com*required+field&o=xs).

*Details*:

- `(?s)` - now, `.` matches line feed chars
- `(?<!` - start of a negative lookbehind, the following patterns - if matched - will fail the match:

  - `[\w.%+-]+@[\w.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{0,3}(?=[A-Za-z])|` - one or more word, `.`, `%`, `+` or `-` chars, `@`, one or more word, `.` or `-` chars, `.`, zero to three letters that are followed with a letter, or
  - `[\w.%+-]+@[\w.-]*(?=[\w.-]*\.[A-Za-z]{2,3})|` - one or more word, `.`, `%`, `+` or `-` chars, `@`, zero or more word, `.` or `-` chars followed with zero or more word, `.` or `-` chars, `.`, two or three letters, or
  - `(?=[\w.%+-]*@[\w.-]*\.[A-Za-z]{2,3})` - a position immediately followed with zero or more word, `.`, `%`, `+` or `-` chars, `@`, zero or more word, `.` or `-` chars, `.`, two or three letters
    -`)` - end of the negative lookbehind
- `.` - any 1 char.