# find recurring pattern with `sed`

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I am using GNU bash 4.3.48

I expected that

```
echo "23S62M1I19M2D" | sed 's/.*\([0-9]*M\).*/\1/g'
```

would output **62M19M**... But it doesn't.

`sed 's/\([0-9]*M\)//g'` deletes ALL `[0-9]*M` and retrieves **23S1I2D**. but the group `\1` is not working as I thought it would.

`sed 's/.*\([0-9]*M\).*/ \1 /g'`, retrieves **M**...

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `.*` is greedy. Since only `M` is obligatory, when the engine finds last `M`, it satisfies the regex, so all string is matched, `M` is captured and thus kept after replacing with `\1` backreference.

That means, you can't easily do this with `sed`. You can do that with Perl much easier since it supports matching and skipping pattern:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
perl -pe 's/\d+M(*SKIP)(*F)|.//g' <<< "23S62M1I19M2D"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/EZwXDN). The pattern matches

- `\d+M(*SKIP)(*F)` - one or more digits, `M`, and then the match is omitted and the next match is searched for from the failure position
- `|.` - or matches any char other than a line break char.

Or simply match all occurrences and concatenate them:

```sh
perl -lane 'BEGIN{$a="";} while (/\d+M/g) {$a .= $&} END{print $a;}' <<< "23S62M1I19M2D"
```

All `\d+M` matches are appended to the `$a` variable which is printed at the end of processing the string.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples and with `awk` you could try following program.

```
echo "23S62M1I19M2D" | 
awk '
{
  val=""
  while(match($0,/[0-9]+M/)){
    val=val substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
  print val
}
'
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `echo` to print values and sending it as a standard input to `awk` program. In `awk` program using its `match` function to match regex mentioned in it(`/[0-9]+M`) running loop to find all matches in each line and printing the collected matched values at last of each line.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was initially trying to do it in awk. Would this be slower than perl or sed solutions mentioned above?

Comment: @aerijman, usually awk is vey fast. Though I haven't checked in this case honestly

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE '/[0-9]*M/{s//\n&\n/g;s/(^|\n)[^\n]*\n?//gp}' file
```

Surround the match by newlines and then remove non-matching parts.

Alternative, using grep and tr:

```
grep -o '[0-9]*M' file | tr -d '\n'
```

N.B. `tr` removes all newlines (including the last one) to restore the last newline, use:

```
grep -o '[0-9]*M' file | tr -d '\n' | paste
```

---

The alternate solution will concatenate all results into a single line. To achieve the same result with the first solution use:

```
sed -nE '/[0-9]*M/{s//\n&\n/g;s/(^|\n)[^\n]*\n?//g;H};${x;s/\n//gp}' file
```

Comment: I did not mention this in the question but in the file, I have these patterns in each line and each line should be analyzed and reported separately. Otherwise this solution is awesome! Do you have a solution for my case?

Comment: @aerijman this solution works for all lines in a file. Each line produced will be the concatenation of each result. To concatenate all lines either use the second solution or see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Your substitution is probably working, but not substituting what you think it is.

In the substitution `s/\(foo...\)/\1/`, the `\1` matches whatever `\(...\)` matches and captures, so your substitution is replacing `foo...` by `foo...`!

```
% echo "1234ABC" | sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/-\1-/'g
1234-A--B--C-
```

So you'll need to match *more*, but capture only a portion of the match.  For example:

```
echo "23S62M1I19M2D" | sed 's/[0-9]*[A-LN-Z]*\([0-9]*M\)/\1/g'
62M19M2D
```

In the case of `sed 's/.*\([0-9]*M\).*/\1/g'` (did that appear in an edit to the question, or did I just miss it?), the `.*` matches ‘greedily’ – it matches as much as it possibly can, thus including the digits before the `M`.  In the example above, the `[A-LN-Z]` is required to be at the end of the uncaptured part, so the digits are forced to be matched by the `[0-9]` inside the capture.

Getting a clear idea of what ‘greedy’ means is a really important idea when writing or interpreting regexps.

Comment: You are right. I added the `.*`.  From your solution I understand the problem more clearly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you know you will only encounter the suffixes `S`, `M`, `I` and `D`, an alternative approach would be explicitly deleting the combinations you don't want:

```
echo "23S62M1I19M2D" | sed 's/[0-9]\+[SID]//g'
```

This gives the expected:

```
62M19M
```

**Update:** This variant produces the same output, but rejects all non-numeric, non-`M` suffixes:

```
echo "23S62M1I19M2D" | sed 's/[0-9]\+[^0-9M]//g'
```